# Youtube Data api search.list order not working

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

Sorting videos from a channel over method search.list stopped working for about three days back.

I tried too in Api explorer from google on web:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&channelId=UCPvnjqveFmBfTWBVShPIcZg&maxResults=5&order=rating&_h=10

Can this be solved on my side?

Is there another way to get all the videos from the channel to be returned via api?

Comment: this has happened to me too

Comment: this also happened to me, hope they fix it soon

Comment: he same phenomenon is happening to me (order = date)
An incorrect sort result is returned also in Google API Console.
It also occurred from March 16th, so there may have been some maintenance and buggy on that day.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of Youtube Data API.

Already reported this issue by someone on Google forum and below is reply from Google employee:

https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/2494861?msgid=2520468

> YouTube is aware the search/sorting functions aren't working as
>   expected – this is temporary and part of our efforts to better
>   respond, review and remove graphic, violative content from YouTube.
>   Thanks for your patience while we work through this. Will update this
>   thread when these features are working normally again, feel free to
>   subscribe for updates.

Also, Bugs are reported for this on issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128673031

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128673552

Both issue have comment from Google employee as below:

> Thank you all for bringing this up here. These specific filters have been currently disabled on both YouTube.com and through the APIs.
>   We should have updates on this soon. Thanks again.

**Update on 27/3:**

Now it's working normally again, as per threads.